# No command 'rvm' found, but there are 20 similar ones

Tags: ruby, rvm

I followed the [Phusion Passenger guide][1] to install rvm on EC2. It states to do the following:

```
$ gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
$ curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable
$ sudo usermod -a -G rvm `whoami`
$ if sudo grep -q secure_path /etc/sudoers; then sudo sh -c "echo export rvmsudo_secure_path=1 >> /etc/profile.d/rvm_secure_path.sh" && echo Environment variable installed; fi
```

I log out and log back in and get the following:

```
$ rvm
No command 'rvm' found, but there are 20 similar ones
rvm: command not found
```

I installed rvm as root, which what I wanted. I added my user to the rvm group and so I should have system wide access. The rvm files are still there:

```
$ sudo find / -name "rvm"
/usr/local/rvm
/usr/local/rvm/src/rvm
/usr/local/rvm/src/rvm/lib/rvm
/usr/local/rvm/src/rvm/bin/rvm
/usr/local/rvm/src/rvm/scripts/rvm
/usr/local/rvm/lib/rvm
/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rvm-1.11.3.9/lib/rvm
/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Why can't my system find rvm?

Answer (score 30):

I solved the problem by the next several steps:

1. `sudo apt-get install curl`
2. `curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`
3. `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm`
4. `rvm requirements`

Comment: just that in latest version To start using RVM you need to run `source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh`

Comment: I love you @vishwakarma09

Answer (score 9):

Simple Steps:

```
1) echo "source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh" >> ~/.bash_profile
2) . ~/.bash_profile
```

All good.

Comment: And I believe it is a better DX if after error report `No command 'rvm' found, but there are x similar ones`, it should be followed by `Do you want to try reloading the current terminal?` and then the solution in this answer should be applied behind the scene if answer is affirmative. WHAT!!!

Answer (score 5):

There is a little trick to this. This is how I solved  a similar problem.

Run your terminal command as a login shell. This is how to set that up.

1. Open your terminal.
2. At the top menu bar, click on Edit, navigate to Profile Preferences and select the Command tap.
3. It shoul open a window as shown [here in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5W5c.png)
4. Select Run command as login shell
5. Select ok and close.
6. Close every opened instance of the terminal and restart.

This should fix it. I will be happy to get your feedback if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

source ~/.bash_profile

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The main rvm page explains this pretty well. I'd re-read it step by step.
Note the difference between single and multi user installs.

https://rvm.io/rvm/install

EDIT: 
"Multi-User Installs - Using the sudo command

The installation process is similar for both installation methods, however, when installing a multi-user

configuration, do not run the installer directly as/from the 'root' account! A"
https://rvm.io/support/troubleshooting#sudo

Comment: I did not run it from root account. I used sudo. But I did get it working by modifying /etc/bash.bashrc

Comment: I feel that the Passenger documentation should have mentioned the part about updating the /etc/bash.bashrc file to load rvm.

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Then run the commands found here: https://github.com/rvm/ubuntu_rvm

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when running gnome-terminal. Each new bash would have to be reinitialized.

It can be fixed by setting your profile preferences to 'Run command as a login shell', under Edit > Profile Preferences > Command > "Run command as a login shell"

Then logout and in again. If that doesn't work, there is a configuration error elsewhere.

[RVM Documentation](https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

You need to reboot after install `rvm`.

Come on, reboot is what solves my problem after I have tried all other methods: open new terminal tab, `source .bashrc`, tried on `.bash_profile`, etc.

Just reboot, what's it gonna take? It costs you couple minutes maybe?

Do not vote to delete me, this is what solves my problem and it is what I will answer.

`export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/rvm/src/rvm/bin"` is certainly one solution, just not a good one, for starter, it clutters your `.bashrc` file.  Just like any problem in computer science. There are always multiple solutions to one problem.

Here is my solution: go through official `rvm` installation on github, then reboot. And you are done. No file needs to edit manually. It can't be more simpler than that.

Comment: You do not. Closing console emulator or opening new tab should be enough. If this is not working you should check if RVM is in PATH variable. If not please add to your .bashrc (user one) `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/rvm/src/rvm/bin"`

Comment: Yes, you do. That's what works for me. I have tried all other method before rebooting.

Comment: This is really odd. I'm using rvm for years now and after installing it always all I did is just open new terminal

Answer (score 0):

> just that in latest version To start using RVM you need to run
> `source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh`

This answer solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Tried all the other answers but this one worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:rael-gc/rvm
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rvm
```

**importantly**
in my case 'rvm' started working after **ubuntu restart**